# How to customize the width of a DT column containing a widget?

Tags: css, r, shiny, dt

I am trying to customize my `DT` table in a Shiny App. I have a problem with a column that contains checkboxes - I added them and I handled using them but I don't know how to make that column narrower because it takes up a lot of space, even though the column itself does not have a name and the checkbox is also quite a small element.

I found a similar problem with a solution: [R Shiny DT rendering shinyinputs breaks the width definition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72985763/r-shiny-dt-rendering-shinyinputs-breaks-the-width-definition).

But when I moved that solution to my app it doesn't work. Mayby because it contains modules?
Below is my code:

```
library(DT)
library(shiny)

shinyInput <- function(FUN, len, id, ...) {
  inputs <- character(len)
  for (i in seq_len(len)) {
    inputs[i] <- as.character(FUN(paste0(id, i), label = NULL, ...))
  }
  inputs
}

module_ui <- function(id){
  ns <- NS(id)
  
  fluidRow(
    tags$head(tags$style('td.low_checbox_width .shiny-input-container{width:auto;} td.low_checbox_width{width:30px;}')),
    DTOutput(ns("mytable"))
  )
}

module_server <- function(input, output, session){
  ns <- session$ns
  
  output$mytable = renderDT({
    datatable(
      cbind(flag = shinyInput(checkboxInput, nrow(iris), "checkb"), iris),
      rownames = FALSE,
      colnames =  c("", colnames(iris)),
      escape = FALSE,
      options = list(
        autoWidth = FALSE,
        columnDefs = list(list(className = "dt-center", targets = 0, className = "low_checbox_width"))
      ),
      callback = JS(
        "table.on('change', '[id^=checkb]', function(){",
        "  var id = this.getAttribute('id');",
        "  var i = parseInt(/checkb(\\d+)/.exec(id)[1]);",
        "  var value = $(this).prop('checked');",
        "  var info = [{row: i, col: 0, value: value}];",
        sprintf(
          "Shiny.setInputValue('%s', info);", 
          ns(sprintf("%s_cell_edit:DT.cellInfo", "mytable"))
        ),
        "})"
      )
    )
  })
}

ui <- navbarPage(
  module_ui("module_id")
)
server <- function(input, output, session){
  callModule(module_server, "module_id")
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Remove `className = "dt-center"` in `columnDefs`.

Comment: It works, thanks! I just don't understand why it works after this change, could you explain the logic behind it?

Comment: Yes, inside `columnDefs`, you define `className` twice, this is not necessary and only the first assignment will be used (`dt-center`). However, the `css` looks for `low_checbox_width`, which is the second `className`. Deleting the first one ensures that the class name matches what `css` expects.